# How can I implement or simulate Views in Entity Framework Core InMemory Db

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, in-memory-database

I'm using C# Entity Framework Core (against a Sql Server 2012 DB) and using the InMemory Db for unit tests, however, the SQL Server DB schema has now changed and includes some views. How can I implement/simulate views in the InMemory database for my unit tests?

Thanks

Comment: Read only Db Set properties inside of DbContext?

Comment: Views don't have to be read-only under Sql Server ! I was looking preferably to be able to use sql used to construct the view somehow rather than populating a "table" with values i'd expect from the view , although arguably the unit test of the view itself (i.e. does the view behave as expected would be in sql any way). So this may be the way I go anyway.